# Azure IaaS VM monitoring

Tags: azure, iaas

How to monitor Azure IaaS VM availability. how to get alerted in case if the VM goes down or gets restarted.

Existing Azure monitoring / Alert  and diagnostics providing alerts on perf counters like CPU, memory and networking. Is there any KPI that we can consider as for to alert in case VM goes down.

We don't want to invest on SCOM and find an alternative for this.

Comment: Look into CloudMonix, if you find Azure portal a little too... limiting http://cloudmonix.com (I'm affiliated with the product)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Monitoring for that and also create alerts and use them based on performance counters (CPU / memory, etc)

Azure Monitoring

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/monitoring-overview/

Receive alert notifications

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-receive-alert-notifications/

You can use it directly through the Azure Portal, or connect using c# for example. All the information you need is on the link above.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have gone through them, what KPI you suggest to alert on vm is down.

Comment: you can use cpu

Comment: I have tested an alert on "CPU Percentage guest OS" metric for the threshold less than 1 and doesn't fire an alert.

Comment: you'll need to implement something like pingdom. There's no free option ready to use. You need to create your own and I believe that using performance counters is the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I had good results with the "Network In" metric.

Set an alert for "Network In" with these settings: number "Less than", time aggregation "Total", threshold "15000 bytes" (see what number works best for you) for a period of "Over the last 1 minute" with a frequency of "Every 1 minute".

Answer (score -1):

How many VMs do you have running in your subscription? If you're running websites or web services then you could setup a site-to-site VPN tunnel and utilize PowerShell scripts to test availability. We use Task scheduler to call PowerShell scripts that perform HTTP GET against websites on specific machines to ensure that the machine is up.

You could also use Get-AzureVM to test for status of the VM.

Comment: We have two web VMs serving the site and can get another VM if we have to setup the task scheduler from 3 rd machine.  But the challenge is generally IaaS VMs dont go offline, if 3rd vms go offline we have the same problem with solution. 

Please share the links if there are any to setup your solution